# The Chrome User Experience Report does not have sufficient real-world speed data for this page

Tags: google-pagespeed-insights-api

I ran a home page of a website through page speed insights tool. Under "Discover what your real users are experiencing" I am getting a result of "No data found" "The Chrome User Experience Report does not have sufficient real-world speed data for this page." I was able to see the result for the past week and this week only I am getting this issue. What is the reason for this result? How could we solve this to get the page speed metrics ?? Please let me know as soon as possible. Thank you.